# Fatal error: Index out of range when downloading data from the Internet

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

There is a function that updates my UICollectionView:

```
@objc func refreshFeed(sender:AnyObject)
{
    fetchWeatherData()
}

private func fetchWeatherData() {
    PostArray = [PostModel]()
    offset = 0
    self.fetchPost()
    self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}
```

This function causes the PostArray collection to be nullified and calls the fetchPost ribbon update function:

```
    func fetchPost(URL: String){
    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchPost(url: URL, completion: { (Posts: [PostModel]) in
        self.PostArray.append(contentsOf: Posts)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

After updating the collection, the function:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! PostCell
    cell.PostArray = PostArray[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

Gives an error message: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range` in line: `cell.PostArray = PostArray[indexPath.item]`

Why is this happening? The data falls into the collection.

Sorry for my English

Comment: What are you returning in `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int`?

Comment: use `cell.PostArray = PostArray[indexPath.row]` as a recommendation you should use capital letter names for Class names not for instance names

Comment: @GregoryHigley `let count = self.PostArray.count
        return count`

Comment: is this correct `cell.PostArray = PostArray` or else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, check that `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int` returns valid count of items.

Than you can check if `PostArray` contains item at given index:

```
if PostArray.indices ~= indexPath.item {
    cell.postArray = PostArray[indexPath.item]
}
```

And you need to make sure that `ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchPost` runs `completion` on main queue. If not, try this:

```
func fetchPost(URL: String){
    ApiService.sharedInstance.fetchPost(url: URL, completion: { (Posts: [PostModel]) in
        self.PostArray.append(contentsOf: Posts)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```